# Applications must be ready for upload on iTunes Connect before they can be validated or submitted from within Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

When I try push my app to review I got:

> Applications must be ready for upload on iTunes Connect before they can be validated or submitted from within Xcode.

What mean by `ready for upload on iTunes Connect`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to go into [iTunesConnect](http://itunesconnect.apple.com) and start filling out the information for your app.  It will tell you when its ready for the actual upload.

Comment: This is also a good answer, for those of us who've already filled out the iTunesConnect: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13368431/2371425

Answer (score 3):

in my case I tried to upload binary to wrong developer account.

Comment: I was doing the same mistake. iTunes was update with one account and for app submission I was using different. Its a dumb mistake but it can happen. I spent 2 hours to figure out.