# Xcode validate can't find app in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I've added a new app in iTunes Connect whose status is "Prepare for upload" and created the archive for it in Xcode with a distribution provisioning profile that specifies "App Store" as a distribution method.  When I try to validate it, I get:

> No application records were found.
>
> Applications must be ready for upload on iTunes Connect before they
>   can be validated or submitted from within Xcode.

I've checked the `CFBundleIdentifier` in the archive's `Info.plist` to make sure it matches the one I used in the iTunes Connect record, which it does.  Is there anything else besides the bundle identifier that the validation process uses to match the app entry in iTunes Connect?

Comment: Wrong account used for uploading?

Comment: Did you create the archive with the correct provisioning profile?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It's because your App is on 'Prepare for Upload' state. You have to change its state to 'Ready to Upload Binary' by clicking the following button on your app page, on itunesconnect. It's on the right corner.
[image]

And then try again.

Comment: That was it, Pedro.  After going through the "Ready to Upload Binary" part I was able to validate.  Thanks!

Comment: Please, click on the check image on the left side of my answer so you can accept it. Thank you!