# Xcode organizer cannot list the all my apps when i validate the app

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, itunes-store

I am trying validate my app, however it said my app bundle ID doesnt match with the one that i define in ituneconnect. but i check hundreds and thousands times it is the same!!

the only problem is the xcode only list one of my apps which is not the app that i want to upload. like here . it is not the (not woowtag, i wanna upload equals) name of the app that i want to upload. any hints ? [image]

thanks a lot

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode validate can't find app in iTunes Connect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13368256/xcode-validate-cant-find-app-in-itunes-connect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you can validate your app, it has to be Ready For Upload at iTunes Connect. When you submit your app at iTunes Connect, and you fill out the forms there with all that information, there is a final step that people often forget or don't notice; I have made this mistake myself several times. Until you do that final step, all your information for the app is there but you have not yet pressed the button that says you are ready to upload the binary. After you do that, you'll be able to validate or upload the binary.

For a picture of the button you have to press at iTunes Connect, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13368431/341994