# Any way to change bundle display name after app is in the appstore?

Tags: ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Applications must be ready for upload on iTunes Connect before they can be validated or submitted from within Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12825724/applications-must-be-ready-for-upload-on-itunes-connect-before-they-can-be-valid)

When working on release of my application, I had faced some problems with profiles, certifications and all that, and had to manually change some values in my info.plist file.
I have wrongfully changed Bundle Display name to com.myname.appname.
And now after the app was approved, it shows this name under the icon.
Of course I want normal name, and when I try changing bundle display name in xcode, when I try to submit update it won't allow me, as it says that there is no such app in my itunes.
How can i fix that? I just want to have different name under the icon.
What's more, the application name in iTunes connect and on the appstore are normal.
What can be done?

EDIT: clarification.
I have an app in the app store. It has wrong bundle display name. After I changed bundle display name, set version to 1.1 in Xcode and I try  to upload it to Appstore it says - "Applications must be ready for upload on iTunes Connect before they can be validated or submitted from within Xcode."
How can I fix that?

Comment: Are you sure, you did ONLY change the name? To me, it sounds like you changed the bundle identifier accidently as well. Some of those plist fields are filled automatically with settings from the project file or other plist fields. In that case, Apple would be pretty correct in refusing your changed App - because the bundle would be unknown as well.

Comment: What is the *exact* error message, and where does it say that? Perhaps you just haven't clicked "ready to upload binary" in iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to go on iTunes connect and fill in the required information before publishing an update.

After you've done that, you can then proceed with the actual upload from within XCode.