# iTunes connect, Xcode validate in organizer

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, app-store-connect, xcode-organizer

[image]

I can't validate my Mac app in organizer. This is my first submission to iTunes store. what it could be? I have already uploaded a binary file last week but I didn't submit for review. Now I modified some of my code,so I want to resubmit to store but I can't.

I have already seen the solution it does not help to fix this problem.
[Applications must be ready for upload on iTunes Connect before they can be validated or submitted from within Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12825724/applications-must-be-ready-for-upload-on-itunes-connect-before-they-can-be-valid)

Comment: What is the status of App at iTunesConnect?  `Prepare for submission?`

Comment: Yes. Is possible to change to ready to upload binary?

Comment: Please fill all the data of your app at iTunesConnect and save it. And check again.

Comment: i have done for several times filled out and filled in the data in store. issue still persists

Comment: Is your app version is same as previous?

Comment: No, i increase app version 1.0.1 & build version is same 1.0.

Comment: Please keep your app version 1.0 and change your build version 1.0.1 Because iTunesConnect is checking for your app version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86997/discussion-between-roy-nakum-and-ios-creator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get this message if you use the older XCode. The older XCode checks if any apps are in "Ready For Upload" state and continues the upload only then.

But, in the latest iTunesConnect, you will never see the "Ready For Upload" state. So the app upload won't work in the older XCode.

Use the Xcode 5.0 or Application Loader 3.0 or later.

[image]